# vue3.x Cannot find module 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-v5'

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

vue3.x create new project, when reinstall , also error Cannot find module 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-v5', when i install fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-v5, npm throw error 404 status,

anyone know this error?
[image]

Comment: if you want to install vue 3 with webpack try to clone this repository https://github.com/boussadjra/vue3-webpack or follow the steps in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64881079/8172857