# After upgrading to Vue 3, and updating Vue instantiation to createApp, webpack build fails with Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue'

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

After doing all the required upgrading to Vue 3, I can't get away from the very unhelpful error message during webpack build of:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue'`

- I updated to the latest Vue version (3.0.4) in package.json
- I updated all the other packages including `vue-loader (16.1.1)`, and going from `vue-template-compile` to `@vue/compiler-sfc (3.0.4)`
- I changed the main.js initialization code to `import { createApp } from 'vue';` and `createApp( App ).mount( '#app' );`
- I have removed node_modules and re-run npm install, so 'vue' is definately there.
- I even dumbed down all the Vue components to literally just have nothing but html in them.

Why is it still saying it cannnot find 'vue'. Most google searches result in suggestions regarding laravel, but I dont use that.

Comment: you could check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64881079/8172857)

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim thanks but not sure how that addresses my problem, as it seems related to vue-template-compile which I have already replaced with @vue/compiler-sfc. Thanks though. Might be useful for others as a vue3 upgrade changes multiple things.

Comment: Check this tutorial for Vue v3 setup without vue-cli: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-vue-js-project-from-scratch-without-vue-cli/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After lots of research, figured out you might want to check the webpack config alias's section, as the Vue build references within the vue package have changed between Vue2 and Vue3.

If you have the following alias set pointing to the Vue runtime, you need to update it.

Old:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js',
    }
}
```

Change to:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js',
    }
}
```

More info can be found on the [Vue 3 docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#with-a-bundler)

Comment: Thanks. Webpack alias needed an update when upgrading fro Vue 2 to Vue 3.