# setup webpack and vue3

Tags: webpack, vuejs3

I'am trying to setup vue3 with webpack and typescript.
Currently I have the problem that whenever I try to run `webpack serve`, there will be a warning inside the browser console:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3413 You are running the esm-bundler build of Vue. It is recommended to configure your bundler to explicitly replace feature flag globals with boolean literals to get proper tree-shaking in the final bundle. See http://link.vuejs.org/feature-flags for more details.
```

Which I do not understand. My webpack-config is as follows:

```
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js"
        },
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
}
```

And this is the tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

I would like to have a configuration without this warning and then move on to having support for sfc!

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/64881079/8172857

Comment: Check this tutorial for Vue v3 setup without vue-cli: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-vue-js-project-from-scratch-without-vue-cli/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the link you got in the error.

> The build will work without configuring these flags, however it is strongly recommended to properly configure them in order to get proper tree-shaking in the final bundle.

This should solve your issues.

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js"
        },
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "__VUE_OPTIONS_API__": true,
            "__VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__": false,
        });
    ],
}
```

It is also worth adding, that [@vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) is the standard tooling for vue projects.