# Webpack 'vue-loader' compilation issues with '@vue/compiler-sfc'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

**The Problem**

We're building a new application and have opted to go with a GULP and Webpack pipeline for compiling SCSS, Vue 3 and Typescript files. Unfortunately, I've spent the last day looking for an answer to a recursive issue where I fix one problem and it reverts back to the previous problem, fix that problem it reverts to the one I've already fixed and so on.

As part of pulling in `vue-loader` an initial error is thrown stating `vue-template-compiler` is a required dependency. Downloading the missing dependency fixes the issue but now a new error is thrown stating a version mismatch with Vue as they both need to be on the same version.

After looking around I'm aware `vue-template-compiler` was replaced with `@vue/compiler-sfc` in v3, so naturally I've uninstalled the former and installed the latter. However, it lead me right back to square one where it stated `vue-template-compiler` needs installing or to specify a compatible compiler via the options.

I've looked at various questions and answers on specifing the compiler in `webpack.config` but constantly got lead back to stuff I'd viewed.

**Attempted Solutions**

[Vue 3 Problem with Vue Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64868632/vuejs-3-problem-with-vue-template-compiler)
[Webpack for Vue 3](https://lmiller1990.github.io/electic/posts/20200406_webpack_for_vue_3.html)
[Vue 3 Supporting Typescript](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-emits)

**Error One**

```
ERROR in ./Content/Vue/Login.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js):
Vue packages version mismatch:
- vue@3.0.11 (<Project Path>\node_modules\vue\index.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.12 (<Project Path>\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\package.json)
This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.
```

**Error Two**

```
ERROR in ./Content/Vue/Login.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js):
[vue-loader] vue-template-compiler must be installed as a peer dependency, or a compatible compiler implementation must be passed via options.
Error: [vue-loader] vue-template-compiler must be installed as a peer dependency, or a compatible compiler implementation must be passed via options.
    at loadTemplateCompiler (<Project Path>\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js:24:31)
    at Object.module.exports (<Project Path>\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js:69:35)
ERROR in ./Content/Vue/Login.vue
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseComponent' of undefined
    at parse (<Project Path>\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler-utils\dist\parse.js:15:23)
    at Object.module.exports (<Project Path>\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js:67:22)
webpack 5.36.2 compiled with 2 errors in 153 ms
```

**Webpack Configuration**

```js
const path = require("path");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        login: "./Content/Vue/Login.vue"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../wwwroot/Distribution/Scripts")
    },
    mode: "development", 
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: "@vue/runtime-dom"
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: "vue-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Package JSON Configuration**

```json
{
  "name": "***",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "***",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "repository": "***",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --config=Scripts/Webpack/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.11",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-run": "^1.7.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
    "webpack": "^5.35.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.11",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder, what is Gulp for here? I currently investigating possible usage of Gulp & Webpack as well but for building component library inside a monorepo project

Comment: @user0103 the primary purpose of GULP for us is to run specific types of tasks in 'Task Runner Explorer' (Visual Studio) either via a watcher or manually. For example, I've got it configured to build Production and Development files via Webpack as well as clean out orphaned files with only a click of a task and without needing a command line or BASH open. This is important for us for a number of reasons, these primarily being an unfamiliarity to the process changes I'm embedding as well as my own laziness.

Comment: Check this tutorial for Vue v3 setup without vue-cli: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-vue-js-project-from-scratch-without-vue-cli/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just as I was about to post this question I figured out the problem. Essentially the `vue-loader` version is incorrect and answering this so another developer doesn't spend hours looking for an answer.

Early on in building the frontend structure for the application I hit an issue where the latest version of Vue in NPM is v2.6.12 and the next version is v3.0.11. Simple enough to resolve just specify the version.

Turns out it's the same issue with `vue-loader` and at the time of writing the latest version is v15.9.6 whilst the next version is v16.2.0. As you'll note from the included `package.json` file, the version specified is v15.9.6.

For Vue 3 to work alongside `vue-loader` it's imperative that the version installed is not below '16.2.0'.

***Edit: 16 February 2022***

The default download of Vue via NPM now pulls down v3. Dependent packages (e.g. vue-loader, @vue/compiler-sfc etc) have been modified so the latest version pulled down works with Vue v3 rather than v2. Theoretically this will mean the problem within the question will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

just run this  may be  solve this problem
npm i vue@3.2.26

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31833945)