# Callback of onMounted is not being triggered in vue 3 plugin that bundled by webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vue-cli

Forgive me for getting long content to explain my problem.

I made a simple npm **vue3-helloword-webpack** plugin. This plugin consoles the simple text from inside the **onMounted** method.

If I bundle this helloworld plugin using **vue-cli** tool, the callback of onMounted from plugin would be triggered. But same does not happen while bundling by **webpack**.

I think the problem is occurred because of currenIntance(I guess it’s a vue instance) is null as shown in below image.

[image]

#### Content: when the plugin is bundled by webpack

[Webpack.config.babel.js](https://github.com/suman/vue3-helloworld-webpack/blob/main/webpack.config.babel.js)

```
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin")
const libraryNamePlugin = 'vue3-helloworld-webpack';
 
const appConfig = {
  entry: {
    'vue3-helloworld-webpack': __dirname + '/src/index.js',
    'vue3-helloworld-webpack.min': __dirname + '/src/index.js'
  },
 
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: libraryNamePlugin,
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
 
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        },
      {
        test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
 
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        include: 'vue3-helloworld-webpack.min.js',
      }),
    ],
  },
};
 
module.exports = [appConfig];
```

[package.json](https://github.com/suman/vue3-helloworld-webpack/blob/main/package.json)

```
....
"main": "dist/vue3-helloworld-webpack.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.13.16",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "eslint": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mocha": "^8.4.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.3",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.38.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "yards": "^0.1.4"
  }
....
```

[vue3-helloworld-webpack.js](https://github.com/suman/vue3-helloworld-webpack/blob/main/src/vue3-helloworld-webpack.js)

```
import {onMounted, h} from 'vue'
const config = { msg: String }
export default {
  name: 'vue3-helloworld-webpack',
  props : config,
  setup(props) {
    console.log("setup() is invoked")
    console.log(props.msg);

    onMounted(function () {
      console.log("Hooray!!! Onmounted() is triggered")
    });
  },

  render() {
    return h('div', {
      id: 'helloworld-1'
    });
  }
}
```

[src/index.js](https://github.com/suman/vue3-helloworld-webpack/blob/main/src/index.js)

```
import vue3helloworldwebpack from './vue3-helloworld-vuewebpack';
const install = (app) => {
  app.component(vue3helloworldwebpack.name, vue3helloworldwebpack);
};
export default install;
```

Result: when the plugin is used by other very simple vue app

[image]

#### Content when the plugin bundled by Vue-cli

[package.json](https://github.com/suman/vue3-helloworld-vuecli/blob/main/package.json)

```
....
"main": "dist/vue3-helloworld-vuecli.umd.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --formats umd --target lib ./src/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.6",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.6",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-rc.10",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.9.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-alpha.4"
  }
....
```

Other codes are similar to webpack version except name and webpack config file.

Result
[image]

#### The other simple vue3 app which is using the created plugin(vue3-helloworld-webpack)

Main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vue3HelloworldWebpack from 'vue3-helloworld-webpack'
createApp(App).use(Vue3HelloworldWebpack).mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<template> <vue3-helloworld-webpack msg="Welcome!!!!" /></template>
```

We can get created plugins: [webpack](https://github.com/suman/vue3-helloworld-webpack) and [vue-cli](https://github.com/suman/vue3-helloworld-vuecli) versions on GitHub.

#### My question

Vue cli version does work. One interesting thing, the same webpack file configuration is working for vue2 plugin also.

But it does not work for vue 3 plugin, How can I do this without using vue-cli but using webpack version ?

Comment: Did you ever solved this? I have the same behavior here when bundling with rollup or vitejs, and importing the component asynchronously.

Comment: Same issue here with vue3 and vite. What an absolute nightmare.